# EAP-TTLS user properties xml sample

Tags: xml, windows, radius

For using the c++ function WlanSetProfileEapXmlUserData out of wlanapi.h I need an EAP User Properties XML file.

At Microsoft there are some samples for EAP-TLS or PEAP MS-CHAPv2 but not for EAP-TTLS.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eaphost/user-profiles)

Does someone have a similiar sample file or can me help out how to change the existing samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following xml worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EapHostUserCredentials xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostUserCredentials" 
                        xmlns:eapCommon="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon" 
                        xmlns:baseEap="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapMethodUserCredentials">
<EapMethod>
    <eapCommon:Type>21</eapCommon:Type>
    <eapCommon:AuthorId>311</eapCommon:AuthorId>
</EapMethod>
<Credentials xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostUserCredentials">
    <EapTtls xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapTtlsUserPropertiesV1">
        <Username>test</Username>
        <Password>test</Password>
    </EapTtls>
</Credentials>
</EapHostUserCredentials>
```

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old post but I get an error 1168 "Element not found" when running with this... do you have any tips for me about what the issue may be?

Comment: I remember that I experienced this error too, but I don't remember the context in which it occured. You want to use `WlanSetProfileEapXmlUserData` right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes that's correct. I've asked a seperate question incase anything there jogs your memory: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62307389/1742551